# "Post" arguments from a Yii CListView

Tags: ajax, pagination, yii

So I have a pagination setup for one of my Yii projects and have achieved the desired result using **CListView**. For the purpose of security and readability, I have configured my actionParams function to only map to **$_POST** parameters.

Now my problem is that when ever I click on any of my sortable fields or my page links, it actually **GET**'s data. How do I change it to **POST** instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't knot if it will satisfy your needs but you can manually trigger ajax updates through JavaScript with: `$.fn.yiiListView.update('list-id',{type: 'POST'});`. In second argument you can also send data and other ajax options like: `$.fn.yiiListView.update('list-id',{type: 'POST',data:{ex_var: 'TEST'}});`.

But to use this you will have to bind the above to click event of your pager.

Another solution is to edit jquery.yiilistview.js (you can find it in framework/zii/widgets/assets/listview). Go to line 82 where update function is located and edit its options like:

```
options = $.extend({
type: 'GET', //<- change this to POST
url: $.fn.yiiListView.getUrl(id),
    ...
```

});

You will also have to refresh your assets folder. But keep in mind that it will change the behaviour of all your CListViews :)

Regards.

Comment: You are talking about Updating the contents of the pagination on the whole. What I meant is on clicking the Page numbers of the pagination and the sorter columns.

Comment: I know, but clicking on pagination links and sorter columns triggers ajax updates through function $.fn.yiiListView.update(). Or did you use some custom solution for paging? Posting some relevant code would help a lot.

Comment: Hey, thanks! The second solution works brilliantly! I didnt wanna update the base file, but since I have no other go, I will have to make do with it.

Comment: Glad to hear it :). As I said before, this changes the behaviour of all your ListViews. I wonder if there is another solution? If you come up with something please post it, i would greatly appreciate it.